# Get Treeview.Nodes.Text without Name

Tags: c#, treeview, nodes

Hi I've a Treeview and each node has name (id) and Text.
When I use `.Text` property I obtain name + text, but I need only Text.
Example:

```
1 - Car
2 - Bike
```

I want to obtain "Car" for first node and "Bike" for second node.

How can I do this?

I use this code to load TreeView:

```
private void CaricaAlbero(TreeNodeCollection parentNode, int parentID, DataTable folders)
    {
        foreach (DataRow folder in folders.Rows)
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(folder["idParent"]) == parentID)
            {
                string key = folder["idArtCategorie"].ToString();
                string text = key + " - " + folder["Descrizione"].ToString();
                TreeNodeCollection newParentNode = parentNode.Add(key, text).Nodes;
                CaricaAlbero(newParentNode, Convert.ToInt32(folder["idArtCategorie"]), folders);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you store your name and text? Can you post some code example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems you store the id and value in the `Text` property , so you can get the `Text` and split it on ' - ' and get the second part only

`node1.Text.Split('-')[1]`